# Passing a variable to event in drag and drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have multiple droppable areas ..

```
for(j=0; j<2; j++) {
$('#dropElement' + j).droppable( {          
        drop : handleElementDrop
    });

}

function handleElementDrop( event, ui ) { 
}
```

How can I pass 'j' to event handleElementDrop so that i can know to which area the element was dropped to .. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do

```
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        alert(this.id);
    }
```

to find the `id` of the droppable (so you now which droppable has been used)

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/r5rzX/

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's data() function to transport any data (not just integeres, even arrays or objects) within elements..

For ex:

```
for(j=0; j<2; j++) {

    $('#dropElement' + j).data('mykey', myData); // set data

    $('#dropElement' + j).droppable( {        
        drop : handleElementDrop
    });
}

function handleElementDrop( event, ui ) { 

    var myData = $(this).data('mykey'); // get data

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` inside the handleElementDrop to get the dropped. I should store the ID inside a data attribute. But however this will work for you:

```
for(j=0; j<2; j++) {
    $('#dropElement' + j).droppable( {          
        drop : handleElementDrop
    });

}

function handleElementDrop( event, ui ) { 
    alert(this."id".replace("dropElement",""))
}
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/Aspaq/

Comment: there is no need to use jQuery  for everything as making calls to function is expensive: use `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr("id")`